# Deleting row without effecting formula

Tags: excel-formula

I have a formula to autofill the date and allow for a blank row between the two dates, However I now need to find a way that will allow me to delete the blank row the following morning, Is there a way I can do this without getting #REF! error?

The formula I'm using is `=IF(C3,C3,C2+1)` which is entered in C4, See image

[image: formula example]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

What I did was Right-clicked row 3 and deleted the row, What I was expecting to happen was the formula to then adjust to `=IF(C2,C2,C2+1)` but that is not the case throwing the "#REF!" code which i understand is because the 3rd row is now gone replaced by the 4th row

[image: What happened]

Is there a way for the formula to not target C3 but instead just whatever cell is 1 row above it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ROW` to get the current row and calculate from there

```vb
=LET(p,INDEX(D:D,ROW()-1),
IF(p,p,INDEX(D:D,ROW()-2)+1))
```

`p` = value of previous row.

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(INDIRECT("C"&ROW()-1), INDIRECT("C"&ROW()-1), INDIRECT("C"&ROW()-2)+1)
```

This formula uses [`INDIRECT`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) to dynamically reference the cell one row above (`C&ROW()-1`). If there's a value in that cell, it uses it; otherwise, it calculates the value based on the cell two rows above (`C&ROW()-2`).